# Preserving capitalization in BibTeX titles

Tags: bibtex, capitalization

I use the LaTeX wikibook a lot and found this [solution](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Preserving_capital_letters) to preserving capitalization in titles, which is to wrap letters (or whole titles) in curly braces. The phrase "In the event that BibTeX has been set to not preserve all capitalization within titles" suggests that I can fix this with a setting, instead of going back into my .bib files and wrapping titles in `{}`. Is this true?

FWIW, I use `natbib` and cite mostly journal articles, which tend to have full capitalization except for articles. Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes and no. The "setting" comes from the style file you use for your bibliography.
Changing the style will change the way BibTeX dos or does not use capital letters.
You might also try to change the `bst` file. But given its complicated structure and the fact that a publisher might use his own style / require you to use his, this is usually not a possibility.

But in general using `{` and `}` is the quickest way.

Comment: Thanks, Carsten! I don't too much convincing to stay away from editing complicated config files.

Comment: @RichardHerron It is actually not that hard to change the capitalization of the title, and it is explained here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53006/21591

Comment: This is not good advice. To preserve capitalization in titles, the right solution is to select a bibliography style that is designed to preserve it. If your publisher requires you to use a style that lowercases titles, you _must not_ force capitalization-- your publisher will just demand that you change it to lower case. That's why bibtex works the way it does. Take a look at [the question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10772/bibtex-loses-capitals-when-creating-bbl-file) that this is a duplicate of.

Comment: What style doesn't do this? Is there any way to fix this without manually changing all the articles' names?

Answer (score 0):

What I do is simply use `\uppercase` inside the `bib` file. For example surrounding the concerned letters by  this command inside the title's entry. This works for me.

Comment: I don't consider this a good idea. Words can be protected from lowercasing with a simple set of braces, and `\uppercase` is not only overkill but needlessly [problem-prone](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=casechange).