# Incorrect case in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, jabref

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [BibTeX loses capitals when creating .bbl file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10772/bibtex-loses-capitals-when-creating-bbl-file)

I have a `.bib` file and I'm using JabRef to edit it.

Its content is

```
% This file was created with JabRef 2.7b.
% Encoding: UTF-8

@ARTICLE{adem,
  author = {Alejandro Adem and William Browder},
  title = {The free rank of symmetry of $(S^n)^k$},
  journal = {Inventiones Mathematicae},
  year = {1988},
  volume = {92},
  pages = {431--440}
}
```

but when I run `bibtex` and compile my file the title is strange since the math symbols were shown in lower case. Instead of `The free rank of symmetry of $(S^n)^k$` it shows `The free rank of symmetry of $(s^n)^k$` (note the small `s`).

I'm using `\bibliographystyle{plain}`.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bibliography style you are using sets only the first letter of a title in uppercase and converts everything else to lowercase.
To protect parts of a title from this, encase them in curly brackets `{}` in the .bib file, e.g.

```
@ARTICLE{adem,
  author = {Alejandro Adem and William Browder},
  title = {The free rank of symmetry of {$(S^n)^k$}},
  journal = {Inventiones Mathematicae},
  year = {1988},
  volume = {92},
  pages = {431--440}
}
```

Comment: Ow, I can't believe. It works!! But I'll spend my whole vacation inserting braces on all my hundreds references...

Comment: Is it possible to use some style which does not change the cases?

Comment: Once you know what you are looking for, [a simple google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=bibtex+create+style) will get you started.

Comment: You don't have to make one yourself, [search for other people's bst files](https://www.google.com/search?q=nice+bibtex+bst+file+for+thesis).

Comment: Also, have a look at [this previous TeX.SX question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10772/bibtex-loses-capitals-when-creating-bbl-file).