# How to capitalize entries in BibTeX?

Tags: bibtex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [BibTeX loses capitals when creating .bbl file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10772/bibtex-loses-capitals-when-creating-bbl-file)

I am using the following bibliography style.

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{template}
```

I have the following entry in my `template.bib` file.

```
@article{ColeMS97,
 author = {Cole, Richard J. and Maggs, Bruce M. and Sitaraman, Ramesh K.},
 title = {Reconfiguring Arrays with Faults Part I: Worst-Case Faults},
 journal = {SIAM J. Comput.},
 issue_date = {Dec. 1997},
 volume = {26},
 number = {6},
 month = dec,
 year = {1997},
 issn = {0097-5397},
 pages = {1581--1611},
 numpages = {31},
 url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0097539793255011},
 doi = {10.1137/S0097539793255011},
 acmid = {270566},
 publisher = {Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics},
 address = {Philadelphia, PA, USA},
 keywords = {array-based network, fault tolerance, mesh network, network emulation},
}
```

In the PDF file, it is showing like this.

```
References

[1] Richard J. Cole, Bruce M. Maggs, and Ramesh K. Sitaraman. Reconfiguring arrays
with faults part i: Worst-case faults. SIAM J. Comput., 26(6):1581–1611, December 1997.
```

I want the title to be capitalized like this.

```
[1] Richard J. Cole, Bruce M. Maggs, and Ramesh K. Sitaraman. Reconfiguring Arrays
with Faults Part I: Worst-Case Faults. SIAM J. Comput., 26(6):1581–1611, December 1997.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Just encase the title field in a double pair of curly braces.

Comment: Or just put braces around the letters, you want to keep capitalized, like `{A}rrays`

Comment: It's closes as a duplicate for now. We hope the answers in the question linked at the top help. If not, edit your question and let us know, it can be reopened.

Comment: Future readers: This is **not** "what the OP wanted" in this case. The lowercasing is a feature (intentional) of the bibliography style `plain.bst`. The goal is obviously a citation style that capitalizes content words, so the correct solution is to find or generate a style intended for capitalized titles (or even to create a hacked version of `plain.bst` with this characteristic-- it's a very small change). See the answers to the linked question for details.