# Set some letters in a title of a cited article majuscule

Tags: bibliographies, capitalization

I use `abbrvnat` as bib style: `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}`. It seems that all the letters, except the 1st one, in the `title` field of an article are set systematically in minuscule (lowercase). But sometimes, some letters do need to be majuscule (uppercase), for instance for a name of a company or a person. Does anyone know how to make them be majuscule? What should I change in the `.bib`?

Comment: @Mico: Maybe this one? [BibTeX loses capitals when creating .bbl file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772)

Comment: @HendrikVogt - Indeed, that one's perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent the lowercasing of certain uppercase letters of words used in a `title` field of a bibliographic entry of type `@article`, encase the words in question in curly braces, i.e., `{` and `}`.

For instance, you might write

```
title = "The Life and Lies of {Albus Dumbledore}",
```

to prevent the uppercase letters `A` and `D` from being converted to lowercase by the bibliography style in use. In contrast, if you're OK with titles being typeset in "sentence style" (as opposed to "title style"), you would *not* encase `Life`  and `Lies` in curly braces.

See also the topic [Capitalisation in BibTeX](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-capbibtex) that's part of the TeX FAQ list.