# References problems in LyX

Tags: lyx, citing

I put my references in in `.bib` file but there are errors appear in the final `.pdf` file

Ex:
the original citation:

> Karl, Lila. "DNA computing: arrival of biological mathematics." The mathematical intelligencer 19.2 (1997): 9-22.

But what appears in the pdf file is

> Karl, Lila. "Dna computing: arrival of biological mathematics." The mathematical intelligencer 19.2 (1997): 9-22.

I want the DNA appears totally capital as it is

Comment: That's how `bibtex` works, enclose DNA in braces (`{}`) to fix it, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10772/bibtex-loses-capitals-when-creating-bbl-file