# Bad bibliography entry formatting

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I am experiencing a weird issue in my bibliography.

I have a bibtex entry like:

```
@online{psqldocs,
    author = {PostgreSQL Development Team},
    title = "{PostgreSQL Documentation}",
    url = {https://www.postgresql.org/docs/}
}
```

That results in:

```
[42] PostgreSQL Development Team. PostgreSQL Documentation, . Retrieved
from: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/.
```

As you can see, **there is an extra comma after the title**, as bibtex is waiting for the *year* field. In fact, if I add a *year* entry for *psqldocs*, the formatting is ok, having *title*, *year*.

How can I fix this? This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[13pt, a4paper, titlepage, oneside]{book}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=3.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\usepackage[fontsize=13pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{wine}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    linkcolor = .,
    citecolor = .,
    filecolor = .,
    menucolor = .,
    runcolor = .,
    urlcolor = wine
}
\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\small}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage[square,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\begin{document}
    \cite{psqldocs}
    \bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

With `ref.bib` containing the above bibliography entry.

Please note that, for previous similar entries, I do not see this behavior. For example:

```
@online{ piezoelectr,
    author = "ScienceDirect",
    title = "{Piezoelectricity}",
    url = "https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/materials- science/piezoelectricity"
}
```

results in:

```
[1] ScienceDirect. Piezoelectricity. Retrieved from: 
https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/materials-science/piezoelectricity.
```

as expected.

Note that using "s instead of braces had no effect.

**EDIT**:

This is the version of the TeX distro I am using (simply obtained inputting *pdflatex* into my terminal):

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
```

In addition, I have fixed my MWE. I confirm that I cannot reproduce the described issue. Any clue?

Comment: While the braces *and* quotes (or double braces) in the `title` field are debatable (at least in their current WYSIWYG form, I would use `title = {{PostgreSQL} Documentation},`), you need double braces for the `author`: `author = {{PostgreSQL Development Team}},`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864. (Note that I'm not commenting on the issue whether or not your outer field delimiters should be `"..."` or `{...}`. I prefer braces, but `"..."` should work just as well in this example, and with care also in general: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109064/35864)

Comment: If "online" does the job ... why not just use "online". It doesn't seem inappropriate!

Comment: Mhhh, I stand by my earlier comment, but I just conducted more extensive tests with your MWE and could not reproduce the issue you describe. The entry shows fine as "PostgreSQL Development Team. PostgreSQL Documentation. URL https://www.postgresql.org/docs/." If you get something different, please double check the MWE and include a picture of the output.

Answer (score 1):

Some comments and suggestions:

- Load the `hyperref` package *last*.
- Since you're loading the `setspace` package, you have no possible valid excuse for inputting `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}`. Instead, please input `\setstretch{1.2}`.
- Instead of `[left=3.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]`, please just write `[margin=3cm]`.
- Do encase `{PostgreSQL Development Team}` in an extra pair of curly braces. That way, you signal to BibTeX that it's dealing with a so-called "corporate" author rather than with a person with surname Team, first name PostgreSQL, and middle name Development.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@online{psqldocs,
    author = {{PostgreSQL Development Team}},
    title = "{PostgreSQL Documentation}",
    url = {https://www.postgresql.org/docs/}
}
@online{ piezoelectr,
    author = "ScienceDirect",
    title = "{Piezoelectricity}",
    url = "https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/materials- science/piezoelectricity"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[13pt, a4paper, titlepage, oneside]{book}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.2}
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\usepackage[fontsize=13pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{wine}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}

\usepackage[square,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\usepackage{url}
\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\small}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    linkcolor = .,
    citecolor = .,
    filecolor = .,
    menucolor = .,
    runcolor = .,
    urlcolor = wine
}
\begin{document}
    \cite{psqldocs}, \cite{piezoelectr}
    \bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for you reply and your correct suggestions. Of course, I wasn't careful while adding new features and packages to my document. Anyway, the extra comma bug is still present.

Comment: My bad: adding double braces for author value, the bug does not show up anymore. That's still strange: if I format my PostgreSQL bib entry as the `piezoelectr` one, I still get the error, while with `piezoelectr`(and other entries) this issue is completely absent

Comment: @LucaF - Did you (a) reorganize the preamble of your document along the lines suggested above, (b) edit the bib entry, and (c) after making the changes, re-run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more?