# Create a macro to automatically italicize titles for BibTeX file

Tags: bibtex

I want to have a macro/command in my .bib file (REVTeX) that would italicize titles of all references I have.

I know I can apply `\emph` on every title entry I have but this is not practical for I already have more than 100 references and I will have to add `\emph` manually. I heard there is something called `@PREAMBLE` (among others) that can be used but I am a total beginner in LaTeX so I am clueless. Thanks in advance!

Comment: this seems to be missing the point of bibtex. The formatting of the entries should be controlled by the _bibtex_ style. It is best to avoid having any latex markup in the bib file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Alright, then how to control it and make it italic through BibTeX style?

Comment: Usually the journal using revtex will mandate a style that implements the journal requirements but in principle you can specify `\bibliographystyle{..}` and pick a style that you like (over 400 .bst files in texlive 2019) (I deleted an earlier version of this comment where I had over-counted)

Comment: Hi @Omar Nagib and welcome to TeX-SE. Avoid as much as possible to edit `.bib`entries, they should contain only data and some minors specifications such as Capital letters -- [check this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109070/140133). Styles should be provided by `.bst` files. First of all choose a style you want or need. Only then and only if you **really really** need, try to edit inside the `.bst`. But be warned, the syntax is not the easiest to handle. In some situations you may define/overwrite some styles, but it would be a specific style-format-command question.