# Book reviews entry in biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

I am using the `review` entry type in biblatex-chicago, and neither the `biblatex-chicago` nor the `biblatex` documentation have been helpful.

The result I'd like to obtain is something at least close to the Chicago Manual of style, but I can't figure out which combination of entry fields I should use to get it right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,indexing=cite,cmsdate=old,sorting=nyt]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
\title{A Good Article}
\maketitle

Citing \textcite{Review1} for his great criticism of A Great Book.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

with `biblio.bib` set up as:

```
@review{Review1,
author={Doe, John},
title = {Me I. Myself's A Great Book},
journal = {The Review of Reviewing Review that Reviews},
volume = {99},
number = {12},
pages = {123-345},
year = {2013}}
```

Which obviously prints out something almost identical to what an `@article` entry would, *sans* the quotation marks. I assume there are some ways of getting something at least a little bit closer to The Chicago Manual (i.e. would print the title as "Book review of" and then all in italics the `origauthor` followed by a "'s +booktitle+"). I haven't been able to get it working using any combination of entry fields including `byreviewer` and other.

What am I missing? Is the `@review` entry entended to be identical to `@article` and all such formatting should be entered manually?

Comment: The standard styles indeed *"will treat [the `@review`] entry type as an alias for `@article`"* (`biblatex` manual, section 2.1.3).

Comment: I believe that's not true of `biblatex-chicago` since using `@review` allows you to access various `entrysubtype`.

Comment: My note only concerns the "standard" styles (of the core `biblatex` package).

Comment: @MathieuB. You must have overlooked the example `bib` files that come with the biblatex-chicago documentation. They contain plenty of `@review` entries. The standard styles aren't intended to be exhaustive; any entrytype aliased with `@misc` can be customized by defining new bibliography drivers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `biblatex-chicago` package provides the `@review` entry type, but some of the formatting has to be done manually via the `titleaddon` field (see [examples](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/examples))

```
@Article{gibbard,
  author       = {Gibbard, Allan},
  title        = {Morality in Living},
  subtitle     = {Korsgaard's {Kantian} Lectures},
  journaltitle = {Ethics},
  year         = 1999,
  volume       = 110,
  number       = 1,
  pages        = {140--164},
  titleaddon   = {\bibstring{reviewof} \mkbibemph{The Sources of
                  Normativity}, \bibstring{by} {Christine M. Korsgaard}},
}
```

With `biber` it is possible to automate this process quite a bit.

First we declare some new fields in `chicago-authordate.dbx` (This file does not exist by default, so it has to be created. If LaTeX can find it, it is then used every time you use the authordate style of `biblatex-chicago`.).
The new fields are `revdtitle`, `revdsubtitle` and `revdauthor`, these are valid only for `@review`s.

```
\ProvidesFile{chicago-authordate.dbx}
\RequireBiber[3]

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{revdtitle,revdsubtitle}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[review]{revdtitle,revdsubtitle}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{revdauthor}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[review]{revdauthor}

\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[review]{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfield{author}
    \constraintfield{revdtitle}
    \constraintfieldsxor{
      \constraintfield{date}
      \constraintfield{year}
    }
  }
}

\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[review]{
  author,
  journaltitle,
  title,
  day,
  endday,
  endmonth,
  endyear,
  month,
  year,
  addendum,
  annotator,
  commentator,
  doi,
  editor,
  editora,
  editorb,
  editorc,
  editoratype,
  editorbtype,
  editorctype,
  eid,
  eprint,
  eprintclass,
  eprinttype,
  issn,
  issue,
  issuetitle,
  issuesubtitle,
  journalsubtitle,
  language,
  note,
  number,
  origlanguage,
  pages,
  pubstate,
  series,
  subtitle,
  titleaddon,
  translator,
  url,
  urlday,
  urlendday,
  urlendmonth,
  urlendyear,
  urlmonth,
  urlyear,
  version,
  volume}

\endinput
```

The following code goes into the preamble (or a modified version of `chicago-authordate.bbx` - in that case, of course, without `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`).
It redefines the driver for `@review` to incorporate the new fields. (The code is adapted directly from `chicago-authordate.bbx`.)

```
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{cms-american}
\renewcommand{\subtitlepunct}{\addcolon\space}

\DefaultInheritance[\except{*}{review}{all=false}]{all=true,override=false}

\DeclareDataInheritance{book}{review}{
  \inherit{author}{revdauthor}
  \inherit{title}{revdtitle}
  \inherit{subtitle}{revdsubtitle}
}

\DeclareFieldFormat[review]{citetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[review]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}

\makeatletter
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{review}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{magazine}%
    {\usebibmacro{mag+news+author}}%
    {\usebibmacro{author/editor}}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{nameaddon}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifundef{\bbx@lasthash}}  and not test {\iffieldundef{title}}}
    {\printtext[title]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
     \newunit}%
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{cmsbibsortdate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifundef{\bbx@lasthash}} or test {\iffieldundef{title}}}
    {}%
    {\printtext[title]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{revdtitle}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{revdsubtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\bibstring{reviewof}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printtext[emph]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{revdtitle}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{revdsubtitle}}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}}%
  \ifnameundef{revdauthor}
    {}
    {\bibstring{byauthor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byauthor]{revdauthor}}%
  \newcunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{music+eventdate}% 16th ed.
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{language+transtitle}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{part+editor+translator}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{bibreprint}%
%  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{issuetitle}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \usebibmacro{editorpunct}%\newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}\newblock%
  \iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{magazine}
    {\usebibmacro{mag+news+date}%
     \newcunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{chap+pag}}%
    {\usebibmacro{journal+issue+year+pages}}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pubstate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}\newblock%
  \iftoggle{cms@isbn}%
    {\printfield{issn}}%
    {}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{bib+doi+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{originally+published+as}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
\makeatother
```

The entry for a review might now look like this

```
@review{barcott:review,
  journaltitle  = {New York Times Book Review},
  author        = {Barcott, Bruce},
  date          = {2000-04-16},
  entrysubtype  = {magazine},
  revdtitle     = {The Last Marlin},
  revdsubtitle  = {Story of a Family at Sea},
  revdauthor    = {Fred Waitzkin},
  pages         = 7,
}
```

Thanks to the `crossref` field and `biber`'s inheritance features, the following will also work

```
@book{testbook,
  author        = {Walter Ordsmith},
  editor        = {Eddie Ditor},
  title         = {The Work},
  subtitle      = {Subtitle},
  date          = {1983},
}
@review{testrevt,
  author        = {Roald Eviewer},
  title         = {La Review},
  crossref      = {testbook},
  date          = {2011},
  journaltitle  = {Journal of Book Review},
  volume        = {42},
  pages         = {13-45},
}
```

The full, not so M, WE

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{cms-american}
\renewcommand{\subtitlepunct}{\addcolon\space}

\DefaultInheritance[\except{*}{review}{all=false}]{all=true,override=false}

\DeclareDataInheritance{book}{review}{
  \inherit{author}{revdauthor}
  \inherit{title}{revdtitle}
  \inherit{subtitle}{revdsubtitle}
}

\DeclareFieldFormat[review]{citetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[review]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}

\makeatletter
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{review}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{magazine}%
    {\usebibmacro{mag+news+author}}%
    {\usebibmacro{author/editor}}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{nameaddon}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifundef{\bbx@lasthash}}  and not test {\iffieldundef{title}}}
    {\printtext[title]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
     \newunit}%
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{cmsbibsortdate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifundef{\bbx@lasthash}} or test {\iffieldundef{title}}}
    {}%
    {\printtext[title]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{revdtitle}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{revdsubtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\bibstring{reviewof}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printtext[emph]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{revdtitle}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{revdsubtitle}}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}}%
  \ifnameundef{revdauthor}
    {}
    {\bibstring{byauthor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byauthor]{revdauthor}}%
  \newcunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{music+eventdate}% 16th ed.
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{language+transtitle}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{part+editor+translator}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{bibreprint}%
%  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{issuetitle}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \usebibmacro{editorpunct}%\newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}\newblock%
  \iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{magazine}
    {\usebibmacro{mag+news+date}%
     \newcunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{chap+pag}}%
    {\usebibmacro{journal+issue+year+pages}}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pubstate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}\newblock%
  \iftoggle{cms@isbn}%
    {\printfield{issn}}%
    {}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{bib+doi+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{originally+published+as}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{KuhnCopRev,
  author    = {Thomas S. Kuhn},
  title     = {The Copernican Revolution},
  subtitle  = {Planetary Astronomy in the Development of Western Thought},
  publisher = {Harvard University Press},
  address   = {Cambridge, Mass.},
  date      = {1995},
  origdate  = {1957}
}
@article{testart,
  author        = {Arnold Uthor and William Riter},
  %author        = {Arnold Uthor and William Riter and Rita Esearcher and Steven C. Ientist and Stuart T. Udent and Peter R. Ofessor and Lewis E. C. Turer},
  title         = {A Very Interesting Article},
  journal       = {Journal of Articles},
  volume        = {7},
  number        = {3},
  pages         = {1-5},
  date          = {2010},
}
@book{testbookt,
  author        = {Arnold Uthor},
  title         = {Long Book},
  date          = {1990},
}
@book{testbook,
  author        = {Walter Ordsmith},
  editor        = {Eddie Ditor},
  title         = {The Work},
  subtitle      = {Subtitle},
  date          = {1983},
}
@review{testrev,
  author        = {Roald Eviewer},
  title         = {Another Review},
  crossref      = {testbookt},
  date          = {2010},
  journaltitle  = {Journal of Book Review},
  volume        = {12},
  number        = {3},
  pages         = {2-17},
}
@review{testrevt,
  author        = {Roald Eviewer},
  title         = {La Review},
  crossref      = {testbook},
  date          = {2011},
  journaltitle  = {Journal of Book Review},
  volume        = {42},
  pages         = {13-45},
}
@review{testrevkamp,
  author        = {David Kamp},
  title         = {Deconstructing Dinner},
  revdtitle     = {The Omnivore's Dilemma},
  revdsubtitle  = {A Natural History of Four Meals},
  revdauthor    = {Michael Pollan},
  date          = {2006-04-23},
  journaltitle  = {New York Times},
  url           = {http://www.nytimes.com/2006/04/23/books/review/23kamp.html},
}
@online{testonline,
  author        = {Bernie Logger},
  title         = {A Very Opinionated Blog Post},
  url           = {http://example.com},
  year          = {2013},
}
@review{barcott:review,
  journaltitle  = {New York Times Book Review},
  author        = {Barcott, Bruce},
  date          = {2000-04-16},
  entrysubtype  = {magazine},
  revdtitle     = {The Last Marlin},
  revdsubtitle  = {Story of a Family at Sea},
  revdauthor    = {Fred Waitzkin},
  pages         = 7,
}
@review{gibbard,
  author        = {Gibbard, Allan},
  title         = {Morality in Living},
  subtitle      = {Korsgaard's {Kantian} Lectures},
  journaltitle  = {Ethics},
  year          = 1999,
  volume        = 110,
  number        = 1,
  pages         = {140--164},
  revdtitle     = {The Sources of Normativity},
  revdauthor    = {Christine M. Korsgaard},
}
@review{osborne:poison,
  journaltitle  = {Salon},
  entrysubtype  = {magazine},
  date          = {2000-03-29},
  author        = {Osborne, Lawrence},
  title         = {Poison Pen},
  revdtitle     = {The Collaborator},
  revdsubtitle  = {The Trial and Execution of Robert Brasillach},
  revdauthor    = {Alice Kaplan},
  url           = {http://www.salon.com/books/it/2000/03/29/kaplan/index.html},
  urldate       = {2001-07-10},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

yields
[image]

Comment: In my version of Biblatex, `by` in the `\bibstring` must be replaced with `byauthor`.

Comment: Could you explain the reason for putting `Christine M. Korsgaard` in brackets in the manual example, please? Is it for the Chicago style? Does that mean that if I want to keep the styling decision generic, I should leave them out? What if you have multiple authors?

Comment: @bongbang `title`-like fields are sometimes subject to capitalisation changes (sentence casing). Words like names that should not change case need to be protected. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864. (That's also why it is `{Kantian}` and not `Kantian`.) Names in the `titleaddon` fields are not parsed as names, so they will always come out as written. With the manual formatting you have to make sure that everything looks correctly, `biblatex` cannot do a lot to help you.

Comment: Thank you. Very informative.

Comment: Does that mean that `The Sources of Normativity` in the manual example needs an extra pair of brackets in order to be formatted as written (title case)? To the way I think,  `\mkbibemph{}` shouldn't affect capitalization all by itself.

Comment: My research led to me to this [Github issue](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/357) , which seems to confirm my understanding about the expected behavior after the fix of the emphasis (i.e. not protecting case by itself). I haven't tried to see if adding an extra pair of brackets will effect protection. From my cursory review of my very extensive citations, Biblatex _never_ seems to change capitalization in titles at all.