# Unwanted line breaks between reviewed works in biblatex-chicago using related feature

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex-chicago

The current version of `biblatex-chicago` appears to be able to now use its `related` feature for reviews, essentially implementing the functionality provided by moewe in his answer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317903/biblatex-chicago-book-review-of-two-or-more-books?noredirect=1&lq=1) question.

However, with more than one reviewed book, this solution inserts newlines between reviewed works.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatexmk
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}

@article{reviewarticle,
    Author = {Reviewer, Ronald},
    Date = {2010},
    Journal = {Journal of Reviews},
    Volume = {1},
    Title = {Reviewtitle},
    Related = {Author2000a, Author2000b, Author2000c}, 
    Relatedtype = {reviewof},
    }

@book{Author2000a,
    Title = {Title A},
    Author = {Author, Anton},
    Date = {2000},
    }

@book{Author2000b,
    Title = {Title B},
    Author = {Buthor, Bruno},
    Date = {2000},
    }

@book{Author2000c,
    Title = {Title C},
    Author = {Cuthor, Cesar},
    Date = {2001},
    }

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{reviewarticle}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

... gives ...

> Reviewer, Ronald. 2010. “Reviewtitle.” Review of Title A, by Anton
>   Author,
>   Title B, by Bruno Buthor,
>   Title C, by Cesar Cuthor. Journal of
>   Reviews 1.

Short of redefining the `reviewof` macro using moewe's code from the linked answer or contacting the `biblatex-chicago` developer (which I'll do though), is there any quick hack for just getting rid of the newlines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the standard styles you could redefine the `relateddelim` per `relatedtype` and could use

```
\newcommand*{\relateddelimreviewof}{\addcomma\space}
```

This is a feature introduced in version 3.7 almost two years ago, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/455.

`biblatex-chicago` can't deal with `relatedtype`-specific `relateddelim`s yet and so the easiest way is to redefine the 'global' macro

```
\renewcommand*{\relateddelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

Of course that affects other `relatedtypes` as well.

I suggest you contact the maintainer and ask him to implement the `relatedtype`-specific `relateddelim` (possibly with a more sensible default for `\relateddelimreviewof`). If you need a type-specific work-around now, let me know, I will see what I can do.

*Since the image upload does not seem to be working, I can't upload an image, so you have to trust me on this.*

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect.  Just one thing.  In your solution in the other thread, you have ", and" connecting the last one of the related entries. Any way to get this with this version too?  While I'm unsure how Chicago *wants* it (I can't find anything in the manual),  the "and" makes sense to me. ... I will certainly contact David though  (I have a few other suggestions too).

Comment: @jan For the "and" use `\renewcommand*{\relateddelim}{\ifnumless{\value{bbx:relatedcount}}{\value{bbx:relatedtotal}}{\multilistdelim}{\finallistdelim}}` instead.

Comment: Great, perfect!