# Problems with writing bibliography in JabRef +Lyx

Tags: lyx, jabref

I have the following problems:

1. I want to as author:

   > Marshal Hall, Jr.

   But , when writing this in JabRef, it automatically changes to:

   > M. J. Hall ...

   How can I fix this?
2. Can I write `$ell$` in Jabref?
3. Jabref accepts capital letters, but when moving to PDF, it automatically changes to small ones...
   i.e.- I want to write G-extensions, but in Pdf it appears as g-extensions. How can I fix this?

Comment: 2) Have you tried? 3) See [BibTeX loses capitals when creating .bbl file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I tried putting $ell$ , but it doesn't help...

Comment: OK. I succeded in 1 and 3 , ut can you help me with (2)? Thanks !

Comment: OK It worked!! I managed to solve everything! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

**Problem 1:**

Each name consists of four parts: `First`, `von`, `Last`, and `Jr`; each part consists of a (possibly empty) list of name-tokens. As usually there are only two parts (first name/s and surname/s) automatic identification of these parts fail when parts are not (1) in the correct order, or (2) when there are more than one space, and then is unclear for BibTeX which one is a true limit between parts. This is solved enclosing the components of the same part in braces and/or using commas to allow BibTeX's identification of named components. So you can write "First Last" or "Last, First", "First von Last" or "von Last, First" and with Jr.  "von Last, Jr, First" or "Last, Jr, First"

In your example, you can enter  "`Hall, Jr., Marshal`", but if you want include "Jr." after the fist name then you can use "`Hall, {Marsall Jr.}`"

**Problem 2:**

In am not sure if you simply want to render `$elle$` in the PDF as is. In this case write `\$elle\$` in Jabref (as well as inside ERT boxs in LyX text).

**Problem 3:**

This is not a Jabref problem, is a "feature" of your bibliographic style. The "problem" could be in articles, for example, but not in books. To avoid this you can change to another style that have not this feature, or modify the `.bst` style file, or make your own style for example with the `custom-bib` package, or switch to `biblatex`, or simply **protect with braces `{}`** the capitals of proper names, technical acronyms, initials of subtitles, etc.

This last solution is self-explained in this plain LaTeX file, as well as solutions to problems 1 and 2:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{marshallone,
   author = "Hall, {Marshall Jr.}",
   title = "About ACRONYMS, {A}CRONYMS and {ACRONYMS}",
   journal=''Some Journal'',
   volume=''3'',
   pages=''1--2'',
   year = 2013
   }
@BOOK{Marchall1979,
   author = "Hall, Jr., Marshall  and E. B. Sheriff",
   title = "The Elements of Style of \$elle\$'",
   edition = "Third",
   year = 1979
   }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end {document}
```