# Jabref, fixing abbreviation for field

Tags: bibtex, jabref

I'm using Jabref to manage referrences. I want to abbreviate **pages** to **pp.** or skip word (**pages**).

%----   BibTeXsource  --------------%

Inproceedings

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{Talaya2004,
  author = {Talaya, J. and Alamús, R. and Bosch, E. and Kornus, W},
  title = {Integration of a Terrestrial Laser Scanner with GPS/IMU Orientation
    Sensors},
  booktitle = {The International Archives of the Photogrammetry, Remote Sensing
    and Spatial Information Sciences 35 (Part B7)},
  year = {2004},
  pages = {990-995},
  owner = {Say},
  timestamp = {2013.09.07}
}
```

% my Question.tex

```
    \documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}% Use this line for the print version of the thesis
    \usepackage{natbib}

    \begin{document}

    %%%%%%%%%%%%% begin Bibliography %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \citet{Talaya2004}\\


    \bibliographystyle{apalike}

    \bibliography{References}

    \end{document}
```

output:

```
Talaya, J., Alams, R., Bosch, E., and Kornus, W. (2004). Integration of      
a terrestrial laser scanner with gps/imu orientation sensors. In The In-     
ternational Archives of the Photogrammetry, Remote Sensing and Spatial   
Information Sciences 35 (Part B7), pages  990-995.
```

Here **pages** is appearing. How can I skip **pages** or customize pages to pp..

Comment: Your bibliography style (`.bst` file) defines how the data should be formatted not JabRef. It only manages the data. So you shouldn't use pp in the database.

Comment: You need to tell us what `.bst` file you are using (if you're using `bibtex` and friends) or which `biblatex` style you are using (how about a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)). Either way, as @percusse said, *do not* add something like "pp." to the `pages` field manually.

Comment: @noewe see edited.

Comment: @user31177 I'm afraid, we'll need a little bit more than that. What package are you using? `natbib` (I suppose you do), `biblatex`, ...? What `\bibliographystyle` are you using (`plainnat` etc.). Just show us a small yet complete document in which you cite `\citet{Talaya2004}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the folowing, we will assume you use `natbib` with `plainnat.bst`, this solution will work for all standard `natbib` `.bst` files and probably the majority of `.bst` files - just follow the instructions below.

If you are using `natbib` with `plainnat.bst`, you will just have to modify the function `FUNCTION {format.pages}`.

Locate `plainnat.bst` on your file system, copy it to a place LaTeX can find it (a good start would be the directory your `.tex` file is in) and rename it (to, say, `myplainnat.bst`).
Open the renamed document and find `FUNCTION {format.pages}`, replace the function by

```
FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages empty$
    { "" }
    { pages multi.page.check
        { "pp." pages n.dashify tie.or.space.connect }%<---- changed "pages" to "pp."
        { "p." pages tie.or.space.connect }%<---- changed "page" to "p."
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Now use `\bibliographystyle{myplainnat}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@INPROCEEDINGS{Talaya2004,
  author = {Talaya, J. and Alamís, R. and Bosch, E. and Kornus, W},
  title = {Integration of a Terrestrial Laser Scanner with GPS/IMU Orientation
    Sensors},
  booktitle = {The International Archives of the Photogrammetry, Remote Sensing
    and Spatial Information Sciences 35 (Part B7)},
  year = {2004},
  pages = {990-995},
  owner = {Say},
  timestamp = {2013.09.07}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{Talaya2004}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{myplainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit** as you are using `apalike.bst` (you can find out what style you are using by examining `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`), here is the guide for `apalike`.

Find `apalike.bst` on your computer (it is probably in `texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/apalike`, on my machine it was in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\bibtex\bst\apalike`; if you have no idea where to find it, open a command prompt/shell and type `kpsewhich apalike.bst` and navigate to that file) copy it into the directory `myQuestion.tex` is in, rename `apalike.bst` to `myapalike.bst`.

Open `myapalike.bst` and search for `FUNCTION {format.pages}` (in my version of the file it is on line 378), you will find a block of code like this.

```
FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages empty$
    { "" }
    { pages multi.page.check
        { "pages" pages n.dashify tie.or.space.connect }
        { "page" pages tie.or.space.connect }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Just change the word "pages" in the fifth line to "pp." and "page" in the sixth line to "p.", so the whole function now reads:

```
FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages empty$
    { "" }
    { pages multi.page.check
        { "pp." pages n.dashify tie.or.space.connect }%<---- changed "pages" to "pp."
        { "p." pages tie.or.space.connect }%<---- changed "page" to "p."
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Instead of `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` from now on use `\bibliographystyle{myapalike}`.

So your MWE becomes

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%% begin Bibliography %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\citet{Talaya2004}\
\bibliographystyle{myapalike}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

the bibliography looks like this
[image]

Comment: What should I search for. Plaese see my file.

Comment: @user31177 I have updated the answer, did that solve your problem?

Comment: It works. But I'm getting gps/imu instead of  GPS/IMU. What have you changed to get it.

Comment: @user31177 Since "GPS" and "IMU" are acronyms, I figured they'd better always be upper case. Some styles convert titles and the like to sentence case automatically, but one can prevent certain portions of the text from being made lower case by wrapping them in curly braces ([read more about this here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864)). So the only change was to make sure the `title` field now reads `title = {Integration of a Terrestrial Laser Scanner with {GPS/IMU} Orientation Sensors}`.