# Controlling title , bibtex, using JabRef

Tags: bibtex, jabref

I'm using Jabref to manage references. I use references both in English and German.

```
    % my Question
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}% Use this line for the print version of the thesis

\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname3.bib}
@INPROCEEDINGS{Talaya2004,
  author = {Talaya, J. and Alamús, R. and Bosch, E. and Kornus, W},
  title = {Integration of a Terrestrial Laser Scanner with {GPS/IMU} Orientation
    Sensors},
  booktitle = {The International Archives of the Photogrammetry, Remote Sensing
    and Spatial Information Sciences 35 (Part B7)},
  year = {2004},
  pages = {990-995},
  owner = {Say},
  timestamp = {2013.09.07}
}
@PHDTHESIS{Gordon2008,
  author = {Gordon, B},
  title = {Zur Bestimmung von Messunsicherheiten terrestrischer Laserscanner},
  school = {Technical University Darmstadt, http://tuprints.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de/1206/.},
  year = {2008},
  owner = {Say},
  timestamp = {2013.09.08}
}
@ARTICLE{Rautenberg2002,
  author = {Rautenberg, U and Wiggenhagen, M},
  title = {Abnahme und Ueberwachung photogrammetrischer Messsysteme nach VDI
    2634, Blatt 1},
  journal = {PFG},
  year = {2002},
  volume = {Nr. 2/2002},
  pages = {pp. 117-124},
  owner = {Sayyad},
  timestamp = {2013.09.08}
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%% begin Bibliography %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\citet{Talaya2004}\\

\citet{Gordon2008}
\citet{Rautenberg2002}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\bibliography{\jobname3}

\end{document}
```

Output:

> Gordon, B. (2008). Zur Bestimmung von Messunsicherheiten ter-
>   restrischer Laserscanner. PhD thesis, Technical University Darmstadt,
>   http://tuprints.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de/1206/.
>
> Rautenberg, U. and Wiggenhagen, M. (2002). Abnahme und ueberwachung
>   photogrammetrischer messsysteme nach vdi 2634, blatt 1. PFG, Nr.
>   2/2002:pp. 117-124.
>
> Talaya, J., Alams, R., Bosch, E., and Kornus, W. (2004). Integration
>   of a terrestrial laser scanner with GPS/IMU orientation sensors. In
>   The International Archives of the Photogrammetry, Remote Sensing and
>   Spatial Information Sciences 35 (Part B7), pp. 990-995.

I want to get

> Gordon, B. (2008). Zur Bestimmung von Messunsicherheiten ter-
>   restrischer Laserscanner. PhD thesis, Technical University Darmstadt,
>   http://tuprints.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de/1206/.
>
> % Correct german, Nouns are written with capital letters
>
> Rautenberg, U. and Wiggenhagen, M. (2002). **Abnahme und
>   *Ueberwachung* photogrammetrischer Messsysteme nach VDI 2634, Blatt** 1. PFG, Nr. 2/2002:pp. 117-124.
>
> % First letter should be capital.
>
> Talaya, J., Alams, R., Bosch, E., and Kornus, W. (2004). **Integration
>   of a Terrestrial Laser Scanner with GPS/IMU Orientation Sensors**. In
>   The International Archives of the Photogrammetry, Remote Sensing and
>   Spatial Information Sciences 35 (Part B7), pp. 990-995.

What  should include / have to change in my code. What should I change in `.bst` file. 
I'm using JabRef to mange my code.

Comment: Is it just the capital letters? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10772/bibtex-loses-capitals-when-creating-bbl-file

Comment: If you want everything in title case, you should follow [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10776/35864) from Torbjørn T.'s link above. If you want the capitalisation to change depending on language, that would be quite hard to accomplish since there is - as it stands now - no way of knowing for BibTeX or `natbib` to know what language a particular entry is in.