# apacite: capitalized significant words of journal title

Tags: bibtex, apa-style, capitalization

In APA style all significant words of the journal name are to be captalized, for example: *Journal of Personality and Individual Differences*. `apacite` package seems to not do it automatically, so I have two alternatives:

1. Manually changes all my bibliography entries (but they are too many!);
2. Manually force `apacite` to capitalize journals (but only significant words).

I don't know how I can carry out point 2. Is it possible? Could someone help me?

Comment: If your `.bib` file has “Journal of personality and individual differences” the information has been lost.

Comment: I thought there was a method to modify the apacite.sty file in order to capitalize journal names...

Comment: There's no BibTeX function for capitalizing. Only for lowercasing.

Comment: See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/12092) for the context to this problem. I'm not _sure_ I would call this one a duplicate, but the linked answers do make it redundant.

Answer (score 3):

If your `.bib` file has “Journal of personality and individual differences” the information has been lost.

BibTeX has the possibility of lowercasing titles, but not of uppercasing them, because this requires subtle decision based on semantics.