# Biblatex-apa style shouldn't show issue number in references for journal publications with doi

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

A journal article with doi number shouldn't show the issue number according to the APA6 publication manual. However, my biblatex-apa style (with biber) shows it. Does anyone know a good way to remove the issue number automatically if the journal article has a doi number?

Now it looks like this:

> Weber, M. & Ruch, W. (2012). The role of character strengths in adolescent romantic       relationships: An initial study on partner selection and mates’ life satisfaction. Journal of adolescence, 35(6), 1537– 1546. doi:10.1016/j.adolescence.2012.06.002

But should look like this:

> Weber, M. & Ruch, W. (2012). The role of character strengths in adolescent romantic       relationships: An initial study on partner selection and mates’ life satisfaction. Journal of adolescence, 35, 1537– 1546. doi:10.1016/j.adolescence.2012.06.002

This is how my test-document looks like:

```
\documentclass[12pt, onecolumn]{apa6}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style= apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{testbib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}


\begin{document}

Some text \parencite{Weber2012} and \parencite{belbin1993}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And the test-bib-file:

```
@article{Weber2012,
abstract = {},
author = {Weber, M. and Ruch, W.},
doi = {10.1016/j.adolescence.2012.06.002},
file = {},
issn = {1095-9254},
journal = {Journal of adolescence},
number = {6},
pages = {1537--1546},
pmid = {22749517},
publisher = {Elsevier Ltd},
title = {{The role of character strengths in adolescent romantic relationships: An initial        study on partner selection and mates' life satisfaction.}},
url = {http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22749517},
volume = {35},
year = {2012}
} 

@article{belbin1993,
author = {Belbin, R Meredith},
journal = {Journal of Occupational and Organizational Psychology},
number = {3},
pages = {259--260},
publisher = {Wiley Online Library},
title = {{A reply to the Belbin Team-Role Self-Perception Inventory by Furnham, Steele and Pendleton}},
volume = {66},
year = {1993}
}
```

In this example Weber & Ruch (2012) should not have an issue number (because it has a doi) and Belbin (1993) should have an issue number (because it doesn't have a doi).
I'd be very thankful for a solution :)

Comment: Does `\AtEveryBibitem{\ifentrytype{article}{\clearfield{number}}{}}` help, if you put in your preamble? BTW: There is no point in protecting the title in double curly braces if there is only one word to uppercase, you could also use the `subtitle` field like so: `title = {The Role of Character Strengths in Adolescent Romantic Relationships}, subtitle = {An Initial Study on Partner Selection and Mates' Life Satisfaction}`. The bibliography style can automatically lower case the title (`biblatex-apa` does so by default).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Works fine, but now the issue number isn't there if there is no doi number (but should be there). So for journal articles with doi number there should be no issue number (which works now) but for journal articles without a doi number there should be an issue number (is now missing). I will add an example above...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I must have missed that when reading your question, have a look at my answer below and tell me whether that is what you need.

Comment: Can you say which section of the APA Manual says this? I will fix this in the style.

Comment: APA 6th, Section 7.01 (Page 198): 1. Jorunal article with DOI and 2. Journal article with DOI, more than seven authors --> both do not show issue number (also Nr. 4 and 5). 3. Journal article without DOI (when DOI is not available) --> does show DOI number. Would be great if you could fix this :)

Comment: I know those examples but it's not clear and certainly not explicit in the manual that the issue number is dropped because there is a DOI. It's not clear that those examples have an issue number at all in any case? Nothing in the explanatory notes says to do this. It might be worth asking on the APA website - they seem fairly responsive to such questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the following test to detect whether the bib item is an `@article` with a DOI field, if so, we delete the `number`.

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifentrytype{article}} and not test {\iffieldundef{doi}}}
    {\clearfield{number}}
    {}%
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Weber2012,
  author    = {Weber, M. and Ruch, W.},
  doi       = {10.1016/j.adolescence.2012.06.002},
  issn      = {1095-9254},
  journal   = {Journal of adolescence},
  number    = {6},
  pages     = {1537--1546},
  pmid      = {22749517},
  publisher = {Elsevier Ltd},
  title     = {The Role of Character Strengths in Adolescent Romantic Relationships},
  subtitle  = {An Initial Study on Partner Selection and Mates' Life Satisfaction},
  url       = {http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22749517},
  volume    = {35},
  year      = {2012},
} 
@article{belbin1993,
  author    = {Belbin, R Meredith},
  journal   = {Journal of Occupational and Organizational Psychology},
  number    = {3},
  pages     = {259--260},
  publisher = {Wiley Online Library},
  title     = {A Reply to the {Belbin} {Team-Role} {Self-Perception} {Inventory} by {Furnham}, {Steele} and {Pendleton}},
  volume    = {66},
  year      = {1993},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifentrytype{article}} and not test {\iffieldundef{doi}}}
    {\clearfield{number}}
    {}%
}

\begin{document}
  Some text \parencite{Weber2012,belbin1993}.

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @teeglaze Notice how I changed the `title`/`subtitle` fields of the entries to be more "BibTeX like". See [this discussion (BibTeX loses capitals when creating .bbl file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864); it is relevant for `biblatex` as well): Normally, you give the title in Title Case (capitalised form) and protect only those words that absolutely have to be capitalised with curly braces, you then choose a style that either preserves capitalisation or converts to sentence style (lower case); `biblatex-apa` does the latter.

Comment: Great, it works like a charm. Regarding the BibTex file format: I have exported the BibTex entry form Mendeley, so I assume that the programm does the two brackets so it doesn't have to differentiate between capitalised/non-capitalised. Now, I know why I had problems with the capitaisation of titles. Thanks a lot for that advice too!