# Capitalization of bibentry with bold and colored text?

Tags: bibtex, capitalization

In my bibliography, I want the paper title to be capitalised, red, and bold. That's why my bibtex entries look like this:

```
@inproceedings{2015-3,
    Author = {\textbf{James Bond}},
    Booktitle = {Doctoral Symposium at the 37th International Conference on Software Engineering (ICSE 2015)},
    Date-Added = {2014-12-19 10:57:41 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-12-19 10:58:36 +0000},
    Title = {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{{M}essing with {D}evils all over the {W}orld}}},
    Year = {2015}}
```

This makes the font bold and red, but the capitalisation is not working anymore. Why is that and what can I do?

Comment: Cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/15925

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve what you want, change your `Title` field to

```
Title = {{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{Messing with Devils all over the World}}}}
```

that is, add an extra pair of braces.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{2015-3,
    Author = {\textbf{James Bond}},
    Booktitle = {Doctoral Symposium at the 37th International Conference on Software Engineering (ICSE 2015)},
    Date-Added = {2014-12-19 10:57:41 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-12-19 10:58:36 +0000},
    Title = {{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{Messing with Devils all over the World}}}},
    Year = {2015}}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Once you have added the extra outer braces, those around the individual captials are no longer needed.