# apacite package does not fully handle apa requirements

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

The `apacite` package does not fully handle the apa requirements for capitalization, how can I fix it?

The correct citation looks like this

> Stevenson, R. L. (2004). Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde. New York, NY: Random House, Inc. (Original work published in 1886)

However in my entry, the capitalization of the title is messed up. As Jekyll and Hyde are proper nouns

My .bib entry:

```
@book{JekyllHyde,
    title={Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde},
    author={Robert Louis Stevenson},
    publisher={Bantam Dell},
    address={New York, New York},
    year="2004",
    isbn={0-553-21277-X},
    note="Original work published in 1886"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  This is a question of correct input in the `bibtex` file.  You should write `title={{D}r. {J}ekyll and {M}r. {H}yde},' protecting characters that have to be upper case with `{..}`.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Do you want to make that into an answer, so that I can accept it as the answer?

Comment: I am glad my comment solved the problem.  This is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/15925 and we should in fact close it as such.

Comment: @AndrewSwann When I went hunting for a solution with google that answer did not show up.