# biblatex: How to emphasize but not caps-protect?

Tags: biblatex

Using `\emph{\relax About}` to emphasize but not caps-protect “About”, as recommended by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140071/22851 does not work as expected: it removes the emphasis but keeps the caps-protection:

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}%
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{a,
  author       = {Doe, John},
  year         = {2015},
  title        = {All About \emph{About} 1}
}
@article{b,
  author       = {Doe, John},
  year         = {2015},
  title        = {All About \emph{\relax About} 2}
}
\end{filecontents}
%
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{a, b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:

> Doe, 2015a, 2015b
>   **References**
>   Doe, J. (2015a). All about *About* 1.
>   Doe, J. (2015b). All about About 2.

So, what *would* work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unexpectedly, it seems `{\emph{Foo}}` can be used in my MWE above to obtain an emphasized but non-caps-protected string, and either `\emph{Foo}` or `{{\emph{Foo}}}` for an emphasized *and* caps-protected string.

Similarly, `\textbf{Foo}` and `{{\textbf{Foo}}}` provide caps-protection; `{\textbf{Foo}}` does not.

This is indeed so unexpected that I’d be highly interested in whether others can reproduce this, explain this, and whether this is felt to be a general solution for the problem of removing caps-protection in biblatex.

Comment: biblatex developer confirms this is expected behaviour: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/357#issuecomment-154819866

Comment: They apparently reversed that decision further down that Github thread.

Answer (score 4):

The answer you quote refers to BibTeX; it seems that `biblatex`/Biber work differently and that

```
All About {\em About\/}
```

is necessary.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}%
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{a,
  author       = {Doe, John},
  year         = {2015},
  title        = {All About {\em About\/} 1}
}
@article{b,
  author       = {Doe, John},
  year         = {2015},
  title        = {All About \emph{\relax About} 2}
}
\end{filecontents}
%
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{a, b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]