# amsxport automatically changes capitalization

Tags: bibliographies, amsrefs

`amsxport` automatically de-capitalizes all non-initial letters. How do I get it not to do this?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsrefs}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{amsxport}
\bibliography{references.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. Cutting your code down to a MWE may well reveal what your problem actually is. In any case, it is really difficult to help you without more information.

Comment: You may also need to look at [protecting the case of letters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10772/bibtex-loses-capitals-when-creating-bbl-file) (e.g. when used in abbreviations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `amsxport.bst` style file does not exist. As far as I remember, it has been dropped years ago (there's no trace of it in TeX Live 2012). In its place five styles called `amsrn`, `amsru`, `amsra`, `amsry` and `amsrs` are provided.

All five styles have

```
FUNCTION {format.title}{
    duplicate$
    missing.or.empty
        { pop$ "" }
        { "t" change.case$ }
    if$
}
```

which means that the title is made lowercase. This is the house style of AMS.

By the way, a `\bibliographystyle` declaration in a document loading `amsrefs` does nothing at all. The choice among those styles is done via package options.

What can you do?

1. Find `amsrn.bst` in your TeX distribution; copy it under a new name in the same directory as your test TeX file
2. Modify the function `format.title` reported above so that it becomes

   ```
   FUNCTION {format.title}{
       duplicate$
       missing.or.empty
           { pop$ "" }
   %        { "t" change.case$ }% removed!!!!
           { }% added!!!!
       if$
   }
   ```
3. Modify your test file to be

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{amsrefs}

   % override amsrefs style selection
   \makeatletter
   \def\bibtex@style{amsrn-mod}
   \makeatother

   \begin{document}

   \nocite{*}
   \bibliography{references}

   \end{document}
   ```

Now run LaTeX and BibTeX as usual.

The `references.bib` style I used is

```
@book{a,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={A Capitalized Title},
  publisher={Pub. Lisher},
  year={2000},
}
@book{b,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={An uncapitalized title},
  publisher={Pub. Lisher},
  year={2001},
}
@article{c,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={A Capitalized Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2002},
}
@article{d,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={An uncapitalized title},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2003},
}
```

The produced `.bbl` file is

```
% \bib, bibdiv, biblist are defined by the amsrefs package.
\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}

\bib{a}{book}{
      author={Uthor, A.},
       title={A Capitalized Title},
   publisher={Pub. Lisher},
        date={2000},
}

\bib{b}{book}{
      author={Uthor, A.},
       title={An uncapitalized title},
   publisher={Pub. Lisher},
        date={2001},
}

\bib{c}{article}{
      author={Uthor, A.},
       title={A Capitalized Title},
        date={2002},
     journal={Journal},
}

\bib{d}{article}{
      author={Uthor, A.},
       title={An uncapitalized title},
        date={2003},
     journal={Journal},
}

\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}
```

where you can see that titles are as input in the `.bib` file.

Comment: This looks very promising. Where do I find these files? I couldn’t find them, either by browsing through my TeX source files or by searching. I believe I have TeX Live, and I’m using a Mac.

Comment: @ZachBlumenstein If you can use the Terminal, `cp $(kpsewhich amsrn.bst) amsrn-mod.bst` will do the trick. Anyway, the location in TeX Live 2016 is `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/amsrefs/amsrn.bst`, which you can reach from the finder with the “Go to” menu.