# Problem on the bibliography when there are capital letters or abbreviations in the title field of a bibliographic entry

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

How should I solve the problem on the out put of a bibliography when capital letters change to Lowercase letter.

For Example, it should be:

> AR Setoodeh and M Shojaee. Application of **TW-DQ** method to nonlinear free vibration analysis of **FG** carbon nanotube-reinforced composite quadrilateral plates. Thin-Walled Structures, 108:1–11, 2016.

but it shown:

> AR Setoodeh and M Shojaee. Application of **tw-dq** method to nonlinear free
>   vibration analysis of **fg** carbon nanotube-reinforced composite quadrilateral
>   plates. Thin-Walled Structures, 108:1–11, 2016.

```
 ‎\documentclass{book}‎
    ‎\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}‎
    ‎\begin{document}‎
    The DQ method as an efficient and accurate numerical tool is
    applied to discretize the nonlinear governing differential equations ‎
    and the related boundary conditions in the spatial domain.
    The new transformed weighting coefficients are developed and
    introduced to make the procedure more systematic for the case of
    quadrilateral plates. For this purpose, a two-dimensional geometric‎
     transformation is constructed to express the derivatives in
    the physical domain in term of the derivatives in the computational ‎
     domain x-y (see Fig. 3). The transformation procedure for
    the first- and second-order derivatives of an arbitrary function is
    presented in Appendix A.   \‎cite{setoodeh2016application}‎
    {
    ‎\bibliographystyle{plain}
    ‎\bibliography{MyReferences}‎
    }
    ‎\end{document}
```

Also, my bib Reference file is as,

%%%%MyReferences.bib

```
@article{setoodeh2016application,
  title={Application of TW-DQ method to nonlinear free vibration analysis of FG carbon nanotube-reinforced composite quadrilateral plates},
  author={Setoodeh, AR and Shojaee, M},
  journal={Thin-Walled Structures},
  volume={108},
  pages={1--11},
  year={2016},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Comment: Try with `title={{Application of TW-DQ method to nonlinear free vibration analysis of FG carbon nanotube-reinforced composite quadrilateral plates}},` with two `{` `}` the title should not be changed.

Comment: You are welcome! I think this was already asked before http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10772/bibtex-loses-capitals-when-creating-bbl-file

Comment: @CarLaTeX - Many thanks for providing the link to the earlier entry. I was pretty sure the new query was a duplicate but wasn't able to find a good precedent on my own.

Comment: @Mico You are welcome! I've got that link because I experienced the same problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're experiencing is that some BibTeX bibliography styles -- including the `plain` style, which is in use in the example code you posted -- apply so-called *sentence style* to the contents of the `title` field for entries of type `@article` (and `@misc` and `@unpublished` as well, by the way). "Sentence style" -- in English-language practice -- means that uppercase letters are preserved (i.e., not converted to lowercase) *only if* they occur at the very start of the field or after a "major" punctuation mark such as `.`, `:`, `?`, and `!`.

To override the application of sentence style to the contents of the `title` field, the words whose letters should *not* be converted to lowercase must be encased in curly braces. Applying these thoughts to your entry, you should insert curly braces in two places:

```
title={Application of {TW-DQ} method to nonlinear free vibration analysis 
       of {FG} carbon nanotube-reinforced composite quadrilateral plates},
```