# BibTex and Mendeley - can I make capitalisation reliable?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

It is a well-known fact that if you want entries in your bibliography to have the right capitalisation, you need to add some braces here and there (see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10772/bibtex-loses-capitals-when-creating-bbl-file)).

However, Mendeley (a citation-management app) does not seem to care about capitalisation *at all* when exporting to BibTeX. It will just create a BibTeX entry with the same title as the one in my database. I'm looking for a way to work around this.

0) The obvious workaround is to give Mendeley a proper BibTeX friendly title. Hence, lots of braces in titles.

1) What I'm hoping to learn here is a way to have BibTeX take an entry and just preserve the capitalisation. I would like to have it done with a specific bibliography style like `\bibliographystyle{alpha}` if at all possible.

2) If 1) is impossible/problematic, is there a way to automagically convert a "naive" bibliography file (no braces) to a BibTeX friendly one?

3) It would be off-topic to ask it here, but I would obviously also be happy with a way to tell Mendeley to properly format the exported BibTeX entries, if such a thing is possible.

Answer (score 1):

With BibTeX you have to manually change the `.bst` file, as explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10776/1035).

With BibLaTeX you can simple add the command `\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{#1}` to your preamble, as explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430492/1035).