# BibTeX when language is mixed

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, languages

I have a work written in English, and almost all refs are in English too. 
I used "plain" as style, and, of course, by Murphys Law a few stinkers 
needed capitalization in the title field since those were German or 
proper name. Next I tried German (dinat plus natbib), with an epic fail 
since et al. came as u.a. And of course everything is due next Monday.

What would you suggest?

Comment: You could enclose words that need to be written with a capital letter in a set of `{}` in your `.bib` file. (See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/134144)

Comment: Works fine! Since there were only very few of those, it was the easiest workaround.