# Lower case when using natbib and apacite

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, apacite

**Problem:**

Title for references are formatted automatically in lower case.

**Minimal Working Example:**

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{RN518,
   author = {Naughton, J.},
   title = {What you really need to know about the Internet: From Gutenberg to Zuckerberg},
   publisher = {Quercus},
   address = {London},
   year = {2012}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish,english]{babel}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque varius maximus enim in scelerisque. Aliquam dictum mollis fringilla. Donec eu ullamcorper erat. Curabitur sit amet dolor eget tellus convallis rutrum consectetur elementum ligula. In a cursus magna. Maecenas nec tristique tortor. \citep{RN518}.

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

**The title is:**

What you really need to know about the Internet: From Gutenberg to Zuckerberg

**But renders as (notice the words Internet, Gutenberg, Zuckerberg):**

[image]

Comment: This is intended. The APA style guide dictates that [sentence case](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2012/03/title-case-and-sentence-case-capitalization-in-apa-style.html) be used in the bibliography. You can protect words that must not be lowercased with braces: `title = {What you really need to know about the Internet: From {Gutenberg} to {Zuckerberg}},`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864. Do *not* blindly protect all words in the title or the entire title if you don't want sentence case. Instead choose a different style that leaves titles in title case.

Comment: ... Only proper names or proper nouns should be protected from case change.