# Some issues in elsarticle-num bibliography style for elsarticle class

Tags: bibliographies, urls, elsarticle

In the following document, I use the `elsarticle` class and its `elsarticle-num` reference style. There are some minor but important issues in the output result:

1. The first reference which is a website has two major problems.

   - The url address appears in a new line rather than being in the continuation of the first line.
   - Second, its font format differs from the others.
2. In the 3rd reference, the year does not appear in the output.
3. In the 4th reference, although I have written "`PI`" with capital letters in `bib1.bib` file but it appears as "pi" with lowercase words.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\biboptions{sort&compress}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Here goes some literature review from e.g. 
\cite{Latex,siciliano2016springer,khalil2002nonlinear,shahnazi2008position} 

\clearpage
\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num} 
\bibliography{bib1}
\end{document}
```

`bib1.bib`

```
@book{siciliano2016springer,
  title={Springer handbook of robotics},
  author={Siciliano, Bruno and Khatib, Oussama},
  year={2016},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@misc{Latex,
  author = {An expert},
  title = {LaTeX experts},
  url = {https://tex.stackexchange.com/},
}

@article{khalil2002nonlinear,
  title={Nonlinear systems, 3rd},
  author={Khalil, Hassan K},
  journal={New Jewsey, Prentice Hall},
  volume={9},
  number={4.2},
  year={2002}
}

@article{shahnazi2008position,
  title={Position control of induction and DC servomotors: a novel adaptive fuzzy PI sliding mode control},
  author={Shahnazi, Reza and Shanechi, Hasan Modir and Pariz, Naser},
  journal={IEEE Transactions on Energy Conversion},
  volume={23},
  number={1},
  pages={138--147},
  year={2008},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know how to attach my bib1.bib in the question. I can't find any option to include it in my question.

Comment: You can just copy and paste the contents of your `.bib` file to your question. But please only include the entries that are relevant for your question and not all of your 234 entries.

Comment: @ moewe: I copied and pasted the contents of my bib file. Is that correct? In the question, there are 3 issues which needs all the entries.

Comment: Re issue 3): Write `fuzzy {PI} sliding` (and also `and {DC} servomotors`), see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864. You need to protect words that must not be written in lower case from the case changing function.

Comment: Re issue 2): `khalil2002nonlinear` is not an `@article` it looks more like a `@book` to me.

Comment: Re issue 1b): You could try `\usepackage{url}\urlstyle{same}` but if you are submitting your manuscript to a publisher, you probably should not meddle with their design decisions. If the class typesets URL in monospace, then that happens because the publisher wants it that way. The same holds for issue 1a. You would have to modify the `.bst` file to change that.

Comment: @moewe: Thank you. In this case, only one question is left unanswered.

Comment: I just want to say something probably obvious; going back to the 3rd issue and taking what @moewe said, you could just write `title={{...}}` instead of `title={...}` to protect letter cases always not even thinking about a particular word.

Comment: @BorisValderrama Generally I would recommend against using double braces for the whole field contents since that disables the case change feature completely. It's usually much better to protect only those words that need it and turn off sentence casing on a style level.