# Converting between different bibtex styles

Tags: bibtex

sorry if this is a bad question, or if it's answered elsewhere, but it's really hard to google. I've been pulling in bibtex citations from various sources, and sometimes they look like

```
@ARTICLE{ somereference,
  title = "{Sometitle}",
  ...
}
```

and sometimes they look like

```
@article{ somereference,
  title = {Sometitle},
  ...
}
```

I read that there are some bibtex .sty files that can interpret both formats, but I'm wondering if there's a straightfoward way to convert between them so that all my entries will look the same. I keep manually converting the first to the second when I run across it, but it's becoming unmanageable. Is there a way to refer to these 2 different versions? Google couldn't quite get the nuance of the issue. I would be happy with an online converter that I can use, or alternatively, with something like a versioning term to distinguish between them, so that I can find my own online converter.

Comment: Both forms are valid BibTeX syntax and are accepted by all styles. But there is a difference in meaning: The first will protect the entire title from case change, the second will not (cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864). I strongly prefer the second format. You can instruct your editor to replace `"{` with `{` and `}"` with `}` that should work fine here and should not clash with other contents of the file.