# Issue with \bibliographystyle{apacite}

Tags: bibtex, apacite

I used `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` and gives me the following reference:

> Herfindahl, O. (1950). Concentration in the u.s. steel industry [Unpublished doctoral dissertation, Columbia University].

In the reference, "u.s." should be capitalized . How can I capitalize "u.s"? I notice that `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` does not capitalize the words in a title of a journal that should be capitalized. There are cases where it capitalizes the wrong word. How to do deal with such issues?  In fact, it capitalizes a word after : in the title of an article.

Comment: You need to protect things words that must always remain capitalised with curly braces. So you should probably try something like `title = {Concentration in the {U.S.} Steel Industry},`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864. (It is APA style to use sentence case in article titles, but you have to protect words that must not be converted to lower case such as "U.S." or other abbreviations as well as proper nouns.)

Comment: Thank you so much Moewe.  I fixed it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Does that mean your question was solved with and is essentially a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864?

Comment: Yes Moewe. I noticed that it is duplicate.

Comment: OK, vote to close as duplicate.