# How to capitalize titles in BibTex

Tags: bibtex

When I copy references from Google Scholar to my bib file, titles are not capitalized. How do I capitalize the titles? 
Clarification: It occurs when I copy and paste entries from Google Scholar into my bib file. I use BibTeX, apalike. It only affects words in the title.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify the issue: At which point exactly does the lack of capitalization in `title` fields occur? Does it occur when you copy and paste entries from Google Scholar into your bib file? (That's what your write-up would seem to suggest.) Or does it occur when you create the formatted bibliography? If it's the latter, do you employ BibTeX (and, if so, with which bibliography style) or biblatex?

Comment: Some styles use capitalisation, some do not. And automatic capitalisation usually fails, especially when more than one language is involved. I would do it manually with the `title`, `indextitle`, `indexsorttitle` fields. Also note that you have commands like `\autocap`, please see the [BibLaTeX](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) manual.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that the issue occurs at the initial copy and paste stage, and not later on during the actual creation of the formatted bibliography. Please also confirm that the problem affects only words in the `title` field but not in other fields, such as `author`, `booktitle`, and `editor`?

Comment: I use BibTeX, apalike. It only affects words in the title.

Comment: It's still not quite clear to me whether the titles in your `.bib` file are already in the undesired capitalisation or whether the capitalisation in the `.bib` file is as expected and it is only the output in the bibliography of your document that is not as desired.

Comment: If it is about the latter (the capitalisation in the `.bib` file is title case as desired, but the output in the bibliography is sentence case), then this is controlled by your style and desired. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864. If you don't want that it would be best to change the style (or get used to it).

Answer (score 1):

You could export a BibTeX reference with the proper capitalization. However, if you want to copy and paste the title in your .bib file you could use TexStudio and capitalize:

select the text to capitalize, go to Edit -> Text operations -> To Titlecase.