# Tech report reference with committee name as author gets abbreviated as if it was a person's name

Tags: bibtex

I have referenced a tech report that has as its author a committee name with a number in it. In the rendered references, the number is removed. I want the number included, since otherwise the reference is erroneous.

My relevant bibliography settings:

```
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{sigproc}
```

The tech report entry in my bibliography file:

```
@techreport{KCS12,
 author = {K-12 Computer Science Framework Steering Committee},
 title = {K-12 Computer Science Framework},
 year = {2016},
 isbn = {978-1-4503-5278-9},
 publisher = {ACM},
 address = {New York, NY, USA},
}
```

The resulting reference text, formatting aside, looks like this:

`K.-. C. S. F. S. Committee. K-12 computer science
framework. Technical report, New York, NY, USA,
2016.`

I want it to say "K-12 Computer Science Framework Steering Committee", like this:

`K-12 Computer Science Framework Steering Committee. K-12 computer science
framework. Technical report, New York, NY, USA,
2016.`

Is this possible?

Comment: try `author={{K-12 Computer Science Framework Steering Committee}}`

Answer (score 0):

I almost immediately discovered that wrapping the relevent parts in curly braces solved the issue, after reading [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10772/bibtex-loses-capitals-when-creating-bbl-file) question and its answer. Below is the edited version of the original bibliography entry. Note the extra set of curly braces added to the author field.

```
@techreport{KCS12,
 author = {{K-12 Computer Science Framework Steering Committee}},
 title = {K-12 Computer Science Framework},
 year = {2016},
 isbn = {978-1-4503-5278-9},
 publisher = {ACM},
 address = {New York, NY, USA},
}
```