# Biblatex APA duplicating editors in reference list

Tags: biblatex, xetex, biber, apa-style

This is my first post here, but long time lurker as they say. Here is my problem: When citing an @incollection in biblatex-apa, I am getting the volume editor's(s') name(s) printed twice in the reference list.
MWE:

```
    %!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%TC:incbib
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mwe.bib}
@incollection{Turing1954,
    Author = {Turing, Alan},
    Booktitle = {The Essential {Turing}: Seminal Writings in Computing, Logic, Philosophy, Artificial Intelligence, and Artificial Life plus The Secrets of Enigma},
    Crossref = {Turing2004},
    Origdate = {1954},
    Pages = {576-595},
    Title = {Solvable and Unsolvable Problems},
}
@collection{Turing2004,
    Date = {2004},
    Editor = {Copeland, B. Jack},
    Location = {Oxford},
    Publisher = {Oxford Univeristy Press},
    Shorttitle = {The Essential {T}uring},
    Title = {The Essential {T}uring: Seminal Writings in Computing, Logic, Philosophy, Artificial Intelligence, and Artificial Life Plus the Secrets of Enigma},}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{mwe.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This gives me the following result, when compiled with Biber 2.14; XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019); BibLaTeX 3.14; BibLateX-APA 9.2; and csquotes 5.2j. The editor's name given once in brackets and again without brackets: [image: Reference list for Turing paper and Edited volume]

How can I get rid of the name in the brackets? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: This does seem weird to me. Does using `@book` and `@inbook` give acceptable output? (It's a little different.)

Comment: BTW, you don't need the `booktitle` field in your Turing1954 entry as the `crossref` field handles this automatically.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for adding a compilable example. This seems to be a recent change. I get correct output with TL 2018 (biblatex 3.12; biber 2.12; apa v 7.7) but not with TL 2019 (biblatex 3.14; biber 2.14 apa 9.2).

Comment: This looks indeed wrong, please report this as a bug at https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues (ideally you would check which position of the editors is correct in your APA manual). Note that `biblatex-apa` (`style=apa`) now (i.e. from version 9 onwards) produces 7th-edition APA style, if you want 6th-edition APA style, you need to use `biblatex-apa6` (`style=apa6`).

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I will report it as a bug as moewe suggests. Both APA 6th and 7th use: ...A. Editor (Ed.), Title of Book... etc.For 7th see https://apastyle.apa.org/instructional-aids/reference-guide.pdf

Comment: Reported at https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/86

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in `biblatex-apa` v9.3 after you reported it at https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/86.

Versions 9.0 and above of `biblatex-apa` implement APA style from the 7th edition of the manual, which differs from the 6th edition APA style that versions up to 8.0 would implement. 6th edition APA style can now be obtained from [`biblatex-apa6`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa6) (`style=apa6,`).

7th edition APA style has a simplified type scheme that allows `biblatex-apa` to treat `@book` and `@collection` as well as `@inbook` and `@incollection` exactly alike. Initially it was forgotten to make sure that `@collection` and `@incollection` are handled properly as well, since in the output they are equivalent to the `...book` types. Indeed `biblatex-apa` didn't even have a driver for `@collection`.

In version 9.3 `@collection` gets remapped to `@book` and `@incollection` is remapped to `@inbook`. This means that the `.bib` file can and should still use the correct entry types (for portability), but internally only the `@...book` types exist and the other types are remapped. This is not something a user should normally worry about, but it is something to keep in mind if one wants to modify the style (I recommend *not* to modify `biblatex-apa` or to take it as a basis for building a customised style: `biblatex-apa` was specifically designed to implement the APA guidelines and has to do some work to do that properly, it was not intended to be customised beyond APA requirements).

With `biblatex-apa` 9.3 or above the MWE looks as expected (note that I case protected entire words and not just first letters with curly braces, this is preferable since braces could inhibit kerning [at least with some engines, LuaTeX is different]: [BibTeX loses capitals when creating .bbl file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Turing1954,
  author   = {Turing, Alan},
  title    = {Solvable and Unsolvable Problems},
  crossref = {Turing2004},
  origdate = {1954},
  pages    = {576-595},
}
@collection{Turing2004,
  editor    = {Copeland, B. Jack},
  title     = {The Essential {Turing}},
  subtitle  = {Seminal Writings in Computing, Logic, Philosophy,
               Artificial Intelligence, and Artificial Life
               Plus the Secrets of {Enigma}},
  date      = {2004},
  publisher = {Oxford Univeristy Press},
  location  = {Oxford},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Copeland, B. J. (Ed.). (2004). The essential Turing: Seminal writings in computing, logic, philosophy, artificial intelligence, and artificial life plus the secrets of Enigma. Oxford, Oxford Univeristy Press.//Turing, A. (2004). Solvable and unsolvable problems. In B. J. Copeland (Ed.), The essential Turing: Seminal writings in computing, logic, philosophy, artificial intelligence, and artificial life plus the secrets of Enigma (pp. 576–595). Oxford, Oxford Univeristy Press. (Original work published 1954)]