# Which Bibtex styles preserve Capitals Letters in the Bibliography, without needing double curly braces?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I want to preserve Capitals Letters in my Bibliography, without needing to go through the .bib file to add double curly braces everywhere

Comment: The answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10776/35864 to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864  explains how you can stop your style applying sentence case.