# BibTeX loses capitals when creating .bbl file - Natbib, Havard Reference style

Tags: natbib, capitalization

Yes, I know: It's a feature and not a bug. But it is a pretty annoying feature IMHO.

When I compile my LaTeX document into a PDF, BibTeX converts all capital letters in the title into lower case letters. I don't want this to happen. Ever. I copy my BibTeX code from Google Scholar and I paste it into JabRef. This is nice. I don't to make that extra step to surround my title with `{}`.

My document uses `natbib`. I tried several style files, including `agsm` and `elsarticle-harv`, which are supposed to be Havard Referencing style files. Havard however would not agree to lower the cases on USA.

How can I get rid of this feature?

Comment: The 'correct' way would be not to add `{...}` around the whole title, but only about the parts of the title that need to be protected from case changes (e.g. names like `USA`), see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864. The WYSIWYG approach of bracing the entire title field is not something I can recommend at all. If you don't even want to brace those words that need protection, you need to find a style that does not apply sentence casing or modify the `.bst` file to drop sentence casing (the latter is explained in principle in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10776/).

Answer (score 1):

In general, BibTeX just puts everything in the title to lowercase, unless you write it in braces. That is left alone. I.e., you need to write something like:

```
title = {On a Theorem Attributed
            to {N}ewton}
```

If several letters, all in braces:

```
title = {Critical Discussion
            of {I}nternet {RFC}s}
```

Comment: I usually recommend to enclose entire words in braces and not just the first letter since the `{...}` can have kerning implications (not with all engines), see the examples in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140071/35864.