# How can I capitalise letters in my bibliography (Overleaf)?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm writing my thesis in Overleaf using the `natbib` package and the `agsm` bibliography style to  produce Harvard style referencing. However, I've had a couple of formatting issues:

1. A lack of capital letters in the title of the work being referenced, aside from the first letter.
2. Subscripts in the names of chemical compounds aren't being recognised (e.g. H2O, which appears as h2o and also suffers from the same issue outlined in (1).

I've noticed this is a common issue for which the answer is often to manually add { } to the letters / words requiring capitalisation. However, this is obviously time-consuming and doesn't seem ideal if automated workarounds exist. I have also seen suggestions requiring edits to the `.bst` file of the bibliography style, but as far as I can see these are automatically loaded in Overleaf. I can't seem to find anything for (2). Might I be using the wrong bibliography package / style?

Comment: For the link https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864

Comment: For the capital letters (item 1). If you don't want to add `{` and `}` to protect words/phrases that must always be capitalised and can't modify your `.bst` file, then the only viable option left is to choose a different style that does not apply sentence casing (there are *lots* of `.bst` bibliography styles out there, but off the top of my head I don't know one that is similar to `agsm` and doesn't do sentence casing).

Comment: For sub- and superscripts (item 2) what can reasonably be done also depends on your input. If you just type `H2O` in the `.bib` file I don't think it is reasonable to expect LaTeX to parse this as a chemical formula and typeset it as 'H₂O'. You could use a chemistry package like `mhchem` or `chemformula`, though.