# Latex Reference Style - All letters in 'title' field are typeset using lowercase letters

Tags: bibtex

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.5in, 8.5in}]{geometry} 

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./Images/} }
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2009}{\,} 
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03B8}{\theta}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{039B}{\Lambda}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03B1}{\alpha}
\newcommand{\gsim}{\gtrsim}
\newcommand{\lsim}{\lesssim}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

something \cite{Riess_2019} something \cite{aiola2020atacama}

\bibliography{References}
\end{document}


@article{Riess_2019,
title={Large Magellanic Cloud Cepheid Standards Provide a 1\% Foundation for the Determination of the Hubble Constant and Stronger Evidence for Physics beyond $\Lambda$CDM},
volume={876},
url={http://dx.doi.org/10.3847/1538-4357/ab1422},
number={1},
journal={The Astrophysical Journal},
publisher={American Astronomical Society},
author={Riess, Adam G. and Casertano, Stefano and Yuan, Wenlong and Macri, Lucas M. and Scolnic, Dan},
year={2019},
month={May},
pages={85}
}

@misc{aiola2020atacama,
  title={The Atacama Cosmology Telescope: DR4 Maps and Cosmological Parameters}, 
  author={Simone Aiola and others},
  year={2020},
  eprint={2007.07288},
  archivePrefix={arXiv},
  primaryClass={astro-ph.CO}
}
```

And this is how it looks

[image]

As you can see in the code of reference, each word starts with capital letter however, thats is not how it looks in the PDF. So how can I fix it ?

Comment: The `unsrtnat` bibliography style practices what's known as (English) sentence style while typesetting the contents of `title` fields: Only the very first letter of the entire field preserves capitalization; everything else gets converted to lowercase *unless* it's protected from BibTeX's gaze by getting encased in curly braces. Thus, do be sure to encase words such as `Magellanic`, `Hubble`, `Atacama`, `DR4`, and `CDM` in curly braces.

Comment: @Mico Thanks that works but is there an easier way ?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean by "an easier way". IMNSHO, if you choose to use a bibliography style that employs sentence style, you shouldn't willy-nilly override that setting. However, if you absolutely cannot stand sentence style and are willing to incur the disdain (or even wrath) of the editorial staff of the journal(s) to which you submit your paper(s), simply encase the `title` field in double curly braces. E.g., `title={{The Atacama Cosmology Telescope: DR4 Maps and Cosmological Parameters}},`. I still think that sentence style is cool...

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864