# change reference appearance of apacite (but only for german language)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, apa-style

I have a xyz.bib file like that:

```
@article{name,
title = {This Is An English Title}
}
@article{name2,
title = {This Is Test German Title}
}
```

According to the "APA-Rules" the produced entries have only capital letters at the beginning of the title.
But for german titles this rule may not apply (don't ask me why).

**I want the title to be taken as it is in the bib file. (upper and lower case )**

How can I change that using the apacite package like that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}

Random citation \cite{name} embeddeed in text.
Random citation \cite{nam2} embeddeed in text.
 
\bibliography{xyz}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\end{document}
```

I thought about an `lang= xyz`-tag in the bib-file, but couldn't get it to work.

EDIT:

[BibTeX loses capitals when creating .bbl file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10772/bibtex-loses-capitals-when-creating-bbl-file?rq=1)

I have found a solution. I have probably thought much too complicated.

Comment: @Bernard thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apacite` can be configured to retain the original capitalisation (with `\APACrefatitle`), but it does not support per-entry switching.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite}

\renewcommand{\APACrefatitle}[2]{#1}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{name,
  title  = {This Is an {English} Title},
  langid = {english},
}
@article{name2,
  title  = {Ein deutscher Testtitel},
  langid = {ngerman},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Random citation \cite{name} embeddeed in text.
Random citation \cite{name2} embeddeed in text.
 
\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\end{document}
```

[image: Ein deutscher Testtitel. (n.d.).//This Is an English Title. (n.d.).]

So if you need per-entry capitalisation protection for `apacite`, your best bet is probably the otherwise *definitely* not recommended practice of protecting the entire title with a pair of curly braces. See more at [BibTeX loses capitals when creating .bbl file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864).

---

`biblatex` would support a per-entry switch out of the box with the `langid` field (and there is an APA style for `biblatex`: `biblatex-apa` for 7th edition APA style and `biblatex-apa6` for 6th edition APA style).

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{name,
  title  = {This Is an {English} Title},
  langid = {english},
}
@article{name2,
  title  = {Ein deutscher Testtitel},
  langid = {ngerman},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,name,name2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Ein deutscher Testtitel. (n.d.).//This is an English title. (n.d.).]