# References in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, apacite

I´m struggling to format the entry for the references in my table of contents like the entry for the chapter.

My table of contents ("Inhalt") looks like this:
[image]

Obviously the second entry for "Literatur" is unneccessary.

I prepared an example wich looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book} % Basisdokumentenklasse
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}       % Standard for Linux
\usepackage{ngerman}    % Fr Umlaute   
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}     % links in PDF ohne Ksten (RSt 2017)
\usepackage{apacite} 

% Das eigentliche Dokument
\begin{document}

% Inhaltsverzeichnis
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhalt} % Es soll nicht Inhaltsverzeichnis heien, sondern Inhalt
\tableofcontents        % Inhaltsverzeichnis einbinden


\chapter{todo}
\cite<vgl.>{test}
 
% Schlielich Literatur
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Literatur}        
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Literatur}
\bibliography{bibliographie}  



\end{document}
```

My bibliographie.bib looks like this:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@Article{test,
  author  = {Dr. Britta A. Mester},
  title   = {Auswirkungen der DSGVO auf die IT},
  journal = {Wirtschaftsinformatik \& Management},
  year    = {2017},
  volume  = {4},
  pages   = {12--14},
}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:bibtex;}
```

I only want to keep the first entry "Literatur" in my table of contents. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Unrelated to your actual problem: Replace `\usepackage{ngerman}` with `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`. You may also want to load `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` for proper hyphenation/line breaking of non-ASCII characters (äöüß). It is very unusual to include academic titles and degrees in the bibliography, so I'd replace `author  = {Dr. Britta A. Mester},` with `author  = {Britta A. Mester},`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If at all possible I would try to avoid using manual `\addcontentsline`s in the document body: If not used carefully, they may end up adding entries with wrong page numbers to the table of contents.

Often it is possible to avoid `\addcontentsline` by using certain package options, with additional packages or with preamble code.

`apacite` has a very clever heuristic to decide whether or not to typeset its bibliography as a section or a chapter. When used in a class that has chapters (like `book`), `apacite` detects if the bibliography is typeset in the `\backmatter` or in the `\mainmatter`. In the `\mainmatter` the bibliography is typeset as a section (working under the assumption that each `\chapter` has its own bibliography). In the `\backmatter` the bibliography is typeset as a `\chapter` (here the assumption is that this is the bibliography for the whole document).

So you can get what you want, if you remove `\addcontentsline` and issue `\backmatter` before the bibliography.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{apacite}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\appto\captionsngerman{%
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhalt}%
  \renewcommand*{\APACrefatitle}[2]{#1}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{test,
  author  = {Britta A. Mester},
  title   = {Auswirkungen der DSGVO auf die IT},
  journal = {Wirtschaftsinformatik \& Management},
  year    = {2017},
  volume  = {4},
  pages   = {12--14},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{todo}
\cite<vgl.>{test}
 
\backmatter
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Literatur}%
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: ToC with "Literatur" as a chapter.]

Alternatively, you can turn off `apacite`'s heuristic and force a chapter bibliography with the option `nosectionbib`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nosectionbib]{apacite}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\appto\captionsngerman{%
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhalt}%
  \renewcommand*{\APACrefatitle}[2]{#1}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{test,
  author  = {Britta A. Mester},
  title   = {Auswirkungen der DSGVO auf die IT},
  journal = {Wirtschaftsinformatik \& Management},
  year    = {2017},
  volume  = {4},
  pages   = {12--14},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{todo}
\cite<vgl.>{test}
 
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Literatur}%
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

---

As mentioned in my comment under your question I would replace `\usepackage{ngerman}` with `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`, so that is what I did in the MWE.

I also loaded `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` for proper hyphenation/line breaking of non-ASCII characters (äöüß), see [Why should I use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/664/35864).

It is very unusual to include academic titles and degrees in the bibliography, so I replaced `author  = {Dr. Britta A. Mester},`, which would (incorrectly) show up as

> Mester, D. B. A.

with

```
author  = {Britta A. Mester},
```

I also moved the redefinition of `\contentsname` to `\captionsgerman`, which is where `babel` keeps its language strings.

Finally, I told `apacite` to avoid applying sentence case in the example, since we are dealing with a German document where turning 'Auswirkungen der DSGVO auf die IT' into

> Auswirkungen der dsgvo auf die it

would be wrong. (Ideally this would be language-dependent, but I don't think `apacite` supports that. See also [change reference appearance of apacite (but only for german language)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/572715/35864.))

Note that `apacite` generates citations according to the 6th edition of the APA manual. The current edition of the APA manual is the 7th edition. In the LaTeX world 7th-ed. APA style is only implemented by `biblatex-apa`. See [Is there a way to apply Apa 7th references and citation style in latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/527497/35864).

Comment: I used biblatex-apa and everything works as intended, thank you

Comment: @Klaas Just to be sure: With `biblatex-apa` you also won't need `\addcontentsline`, you can use the `heading` option of `\printbibliography`. You probably want something like `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]` or `\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]`.

Comment: Even better, thanks!