# Can not get the natbib bibliography package to show all authors' last name, using IEEE style

Tags: natbib, ieeetran

I am having a problem with getting my bibliography to show full last name for multiple authors. Here are two examples of my code and the compiled output:

```
@article{12_equility,
  author = {M. Hardt, E. Price and N. Srebro},
  title={Equality of Opportunity in Supervised Learning},
  journal = "arXiv",
  year = "2016",
  url={https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02413 },
  note = {[accessed: 14.11.2020]}
  }

@article{10_FutureCriminals,
  author = {J. Angwin, J. Larson, S. Mattu and L Kirchner},
  title={Machine Bias: There’s software used across the country to predict future criminals. And it’s biased against blacks.},
  journal = {ProPublica},
  year = {2016},
  url={https://www.propublica.org/article/machine-bias-risk-assessments-in-criminal-sentencing},
  note = {[accessed: 15.11.2020]}
  }
```

becomes:

```
 E. P. M.Hardt and N.Srebro, “Equality of opportunity in supervised learning,”arXiv, 2016,[accessed: 14.11.2020]. [Online]. Available: https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02413
```

```
S.  M.  J.  Angwin,  J.  Larson  and  L.  Kirchner,  “Machine  bias:   There’s  software  usedacross the country to predict future criminals. and it’s biased against blacks.”ProPublica,2016,  [accessed:   15.11.2020].  [Online].  Available:   https://www.propublica.org/article/machine-bias-risk-assessments-in-criminal-sentencing
```

This is all the code I have currently related to the bibliography:

```
\usepackage[sort, numbers]{natbib}
```

```
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{references.bib}
```

If it is related then I am using Overleaf and I do not have much experience with Latex.

[Solved] I found it out. I need to put "and" instead of "," between all authors.

```
@article{12_equility,
  author = {M. Hardt and E. Price and N. Srebro},
  title={Equality of Opportunity in Supervised Learning},
  journal = "arXiv",
  year = "2016",
  url={https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02413 },
  note = {[accessed: 14.11.2020]}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the `author` field in double curly braces, like this:

```
author = {{M. Hardt, E. Price and N. Srebro}}
```

You could use the same trick for other fields - e.g. to retain the capitalization in `title`.

Comment: This is generally not recommended since it does not allow BibTeX to properly parse and understand the name list. Only then can BibTeX format the names as desired by the style. All names should be separated with `and`. If the name field is wrapped in curly braces it will always appear as is. This will go horribly wrong with author-year citations and may cause issues with styles that prefer "Family, Given" name order.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In current circumstances the OP may have skipped the title capitalization issue. As I mostly use the IEEE style myself, I prefer to take control of the capitalization and this is probably the easiest way of doing so.

Comment: There is a difference between adding doubly curly braces to title fields (where you 'only' disable the capitalisation feature: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864) and adding curly braces to name fields (where you can completely disable name parsing and with it sorting and name formatting). I wouldn't recommend using the WYSIWG `<field> = {{<content>}},` unconditionally in either setting, but it is usually worse if wrongly applied in name fields than in title-like fields.