# Mistake in Bibliography with bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have just written a paper in LaTeX, for the bibliography I used `natbib`. But there is the following mistake:

In `file.bib` I input as

```
@book{driscoll2002schwarz,
  title={Schwarz-Christoffel mapping},
  author={T. A. Driscoll and L. N. Trefethen},
  volume={8},
  year={2002},
  language={English},
  publisher={Cambridge University Press}
}
```

After Typeset, the result----->

> [12] T. A. Driscoll and L. N. Trefethen, *Schwarz-christoffel mapping*,...

The mistake in "Schwarz-christoffel", I want to be "Schwarz-Christoffel"

Comment: Surround the title or Christoffel with additional braces.

Comment: You want `title={{Schwarz-Christoffel} Mapping},` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864. Proper nouns (and all things that must be capitalised at all times) need to be protected from possible case change with an additional pair of braces.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BibTeX loses capitals when creating .bbl file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10772/bibtex-loses-capitals-when-creating-bbl-file)

Comment: @moewe thank you so much!