# Citing two authors with & instead of and

Tags: citing, natbib

I would like the citation for `\citet{sample}` to appear as:

`Jonas & Brothers (2022)` instead of `Jonas and Brothers (2022)`.

How would you change `and` to `&` in the case of two-author citations?

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: @Mico, thanks for the reply. I use \bibliographystyle{apalike}. I am sorry for not posting the entire code, but I think I am using natbib package.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. One more question (sorry): Do you want to employ `&` as the conjunction both in the citation call-out and in the formatted bibliographic entry, or just in the citation call-out?

Comment: @Mico, thanks for the specific question! I didn't even think about this, but it is important. Basically, in the actual paper, I want only two-author citations have "&" and any citation with more than two people with "et al." citation. In reference, I would like to have any multiple author (2 or more) citations to have "&". I hope I explained this correctly :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you employ the `apalike` bibliography style -- BTW, `apalike` dates back to 1988 [!] and does not embed *current* APA formatting guidelines -- I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `apalike.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `apalike-ampersand.bst`. (Do *not* edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open the file `apalike-ampersand.bst` in an editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- Locate both instances of the hard-coded string `" and "` in the bst file. (In my copy of the file, they occur on lines 225 and 851.) The first instance affects the formatting of multiple-author bibliographic entries, and the second affects the formatting of two-author citation call-outs.
- Change both instances to `"~\& "`.
- Save the file `apalike-ampersand.bst` either in the directory that contains your main tex file or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the second option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution in a suitable manner. (If you have no idea that the preceding sentence means, I suggest you employ the first option.)
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` to `\bibliographystyle{apalike-ampersand}` and perform a full recompilation run -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- to propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

---

Here's a minimal example and associated screen shot that put these ideas to work.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
% Create a sample bib file on the fly:
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{jb:2022, author={Xavier Jonas and Yves Brothers}, title={Thoughts}, year=2022}
@misc{abc:3001, author={Anne Author and Brenda Branford and Chiara Cavendish}, title = {Thoughts}, year=3001}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike-ampersand}

\begin{document}
\citet{jb:2022}, \citet{abc:3001}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Mico, thank you so much! I am going to try that very soon! I just have one additional question. Do you know if the title in the reference section (bibliography) are capitalized? For example, I would like to have the company name "The Magic Behind Tiffay & Co" appear as it is in the paper's title, but it appears like "The magic behind tiffay & co."

Comment: @FrankSwanton - You're most welcome. Regarding  your follow-up question, about why the `apalike` style tells BibTeX to lowercase all letters but the very first in the `title` field: Please see the posting [BibTeX loses capitals when creating .bbl file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/5001). The upshot: If the string "... The Magic Behind Tiffay & Co ... " occurs in the `title` field of an entry and if you wish to keep the uppercase letters, they have to be "protected" from being converted to lowercase by encasing the string in curly braces: `"... {The Magic Behind Tiffay \& Co} ... "`.

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked! Happy March!