# BibTex and capitalized letters

Tags: bibtex

I am writing my PhD thesis and stumbled over a small issue with my citations. I am using TexMaker to write my thesis. I am using Citavi to orgnaize my .bib file and in there, the titles are correct in terms of capitalized articles (see attached image)
[image: Title in the .bib file generated by Citavi]

Now, if I use BibTex it generates the .bbl file with all the citations I am using in may file. In there only the first letter is capitalized
[image: Title in the .bbl file created by BibTex]

I found in a very informative article from [Claus O. Wilke](https://clauswilke.com/blog/2015/10/02/bibtex/) that this seems to be a known issue wit BibTex. His solution is to use {} for the words that should be capitalized. Now as my thesis has around 200 citations this would be a massive hustle.

Is there any way to "fine tune" how the format of the .bbl file will look like after I use BibTex? I'd rather just use Citavi and organize all my sources in there, then export it to a .bib file and simply use BibTex with the exact same format as in the generated .bib file.

Comment: Just read about "Bibltex" and "biber" and how this isn't a problem anymore?

Comment: You can either use a different BibTeX style that provides the capitalization you desire or, with the current style, in the `.bib` file, embrace those letters that you wish to be unaffected by BiBTeX's machinations: `{A}dlayer-{F}ree {L}arge-{A}rea...`

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult to add {...} around your capital letters in your .bib file. A regular expression could do it.

Comment: The output you are seeing is a feature of your style. The best input in your case would be `title = {Adlayer-Free Large-Area Single Crystal Graphene Grown on a {Cu(111)} Foil},` with title case and brace protection for proper nouns/abbreviations etc. If you don't want the title to be converted to sentence case, the best solution is to use a different style (or to modify the current style to stop using sentence case). Ad-hoc brace protection for all capital letters or the entire title is generally not a great idea.

Answer (score 2):

For BibTeX: it is not a "known issue". It is "by-design". If you want to use BibTeX, then you will need to either

1. follow the design rules and put braces around enforced capitalizations in the title; or
2. use a bibliographic style that doesn't do the automatic lower case conversion. (See e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10776/119).)

If you don't want to do all the retyping by-hand, and if you don't want to go through the harrowing experience of making your own `.bst` file, and if you trust that you have correctly capitalized every entry yourself in the original source, you can just make sure *every* title is [doubly encased in braces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237275/119). You can automate this by passing the generated (from your citation manager) `.bib` file through a filter to double-brace all article titles. For example, the following `sed` invocation:

```
sed -e "s/title\s*=\s*{\(.*\)}/title = {{\1}}/g" <filename.bib>
```

should do the trick. (There may be unintended consequences, though. See the comments in the answer linked above.)

---

Biblatex is a different implementation of bibliography. If you wish to use it, you should [read its manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex?lang=en). (It requires some [small number of] additional changes to your document.) In biblatex whether the title is converted to lowercase again depends on the document language and the bibliography style used; but the standard styles do not do any conversion.

Comment: The `biblatex` standard styles do not apply sentence casing by default. Some contributed styles like `biblatex-apa` and `biblatex-trad` do and generally use the language-sensitive `\MakeSentenceCase*` that changes the case only for languages where it makes sense. Of course this relies on the user marking up the languages correctly.

Comment: @moewe: I may be misinterpreting it, but the manual states (page 264, footnote 38) "By default, converting to sentence case is enabled for the following language identifiers:
american, british, canadian, english, australian, newzealand as well as the
aliases USenglish and UKenglish." Does this mean something different?

Comment: It means that sentence casing is enabled *if* the command `\MakeSentenceCase*` is used. But the standard styles don't use it, so you get no sentence casing even with those languages.

Comment: @moewe: ah, I see. Thanks for the clarification, I'll edit the answer.