# lowercase in the generated bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I have a problem with my bibliography, the words in uppercase appear in lowercase in the generated bibliography as shown in the following figure:

[image]
Here is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
    @article{Ref1,
        title={GGA and GGA+U study},
        author={A author, B author},
        journal={Journal},
        volume={1},
        number={1},
        pages={1--131},
        year={2025},
        publisher={Pub}
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\cite{Ref1}
    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: either use a style which doesn't do sentence casing, or protect the words with braces: `title={{GGA} and {GGA+U} study}`

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I have more than 280 references. I'm looking for a simpler solution.

Comment: as I wrote: you then need another style. Or use biblatex + biber.

Comment: can you give me more details?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864.