# Why is my Bibliography text in lowercase?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

i have this code in my bib file:

```
@article{FDP_NZZ,
    JOURNAL = "NZZ",
    AUTHOR = "Erich Aschwanden",
    TITLE = "Die FDP setzt im Wahlkampf auf Microtargeting",
    MONTH = "Februar",
    YEAR = "2019" ,
    NOTE = , 
}
```

and the result is:
[image]

Why is the red underlined part in lowercase? I want it to be like the code (Die FDP setzt im Wahlkampf auf Microtargeting).

Comment: Check this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10772/bibtex-loses-capitals-when-creating-bbl-file

Comment: If you are really using `biblatex` as your tagging suggests you may want to set add `langid = {nswissgerman},` to your entry to show that it is written in (Swiss) German. In that case `biblatex` will not apply sentence case to its title.