# Make natbib keep bibliography capitalisation as-is?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

Minimum reproducible example:

```tex
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

Example citation: \cite{loenen2014type}

\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{reference.bib}

\end{document}
```

```
reference.bib
@article{loenen2014type,
    title={Type I restriction enzymes and their relatives},
    author={Loenen, Wil AM and Dryden, David TF and Raleigh, Elisabeth A and Wilson, Geoffrey G},
    journal={Nucleic acids research},
    volume={42},
    number={1},
    pages={20--44},
    year={2014},
    publisher={Oxford University Press}
}
```

Compiling `main.tex` produces:
[image: result]

Where the letter 'i' in "Type I" is not correctly capitalised.
Now I know you can add an extra layer of braces to force
keeping the capitalisation, but is it possible to just tell
natbib to "keep it as-is"? To be fair, many BibTeX citation suppliers
simply just use one layer of braces regardless of any uppercase letters
in the title, and it would be much more time-consuming and error-prone
if you correct every of them manually.

Also `\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{#1}` only works for BibLaTeX.
Wonder if there's a natbib equivalent.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your code uses bibtex, why the tag biblatex?

Comment: @Mensch because my current solution uses BibLaTeX? Nah I'll remove it. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to the question but a temporary solution using BibLaTeX:

```tex
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}

\begin{document}

Example citation: \cite{loenen2014type}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Looks like `\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{#1}` is not even required.

Comment: [As in bibtex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10775/106162) this is probably style-dependent.