How to capitalize Abbreviations in the Reference Section in Overleaf?
I'm working on a document in Overleaf and noticed that the abbreviations in my reference section (e.g., SDN etc.) appear in small letters  instead of capital letters.

I use IEEE-template:
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} 
\bibliography{main} % bib file name


Is there any suggestion to fix it?

Please show example of bib data. The standard method is to use {SDN} and  {Sagins}. The extra braces tells bibtex to leave it be

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864
